# Display area on D3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having problem displaying area on D3 graph. I'm guessing problem is in data format(?) but I'm not sure. I'm total d3 library beginner. I am using d3 v5 version. I tried to find some simple examples but most of code I found is really complex and for some old versions.

```
some_data = [
  {
    'width': 10,
    'height': 0.2,
  },
  {
    'width': 11,
    'height': 0.3,
  },
  {
    'width': 12,
    'height': 0.4,
  },
  {
    'width': 13,
    'height': 0.5,
  }
];

var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the area
var area = d3.area()
  .x(function (d) {
      console.log('x');
      return x(d.width);
  })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function (d) {
      return y(d.height);
  });

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.width);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.height);
  });


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');


// format the data
this.some_data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.width = d.width;
    d.height = +d.height;
});

// scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(this.some_data, function (d) {
    return d.width;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(this.some_data, function (d) {
    return d.height;
})]);


// add the area
svg.append('path')
  .data(this.some_data)
  .attr('class', 'area')
  .attr('d', area);

// add the valueline path.
svg.append('path')
  .data(this.some_data)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', valueline);

// add the X Axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the Y Axis
svg.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Area is not showing at all and I'm getting following error messages:

> ERROR in src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(45,20): error
>   TS2339: Property 'width' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
>   src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(49,20): error TS2339:
>   Property 'height' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
>   src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(55,20): error TS2339:
>   Property 'width' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
>   src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(58,20): error TS2339:
>   Property 'height' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
>   src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(89,18): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type 'Area<[number, number]>' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ValueFn'.   Types of
>   parameters 'data' and 'datum' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ 'width': number; 'height': number; }' is not assignable to type '[number, number][]'.
>         Property 'length' is missing in type '{ 'width': number; 'height': number; }'. src/app/histogram/histogram.component.ts(95,18):
>   error TS2345: Argument of type 'Line<[number, number]>' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn'.   Types of
>   parameters 'data' and 'datum' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ 'width': number; 'height': number; }' is not assignable to type '[number, number][]'.

Comment: What do you expect to see? make a simple drawing. And make a sandbox example.

Comment: something similar like that: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/119a138ef9bd1d8f0a8d57ea72355252

Answer (score -1):

If you copy an  example copy it correct

```
svg.append('path')
  .data([this.some_data])
  .attr('class', 'area')
  .attr('d', area);

svg.append('path')
  .data([this.some_data])
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', valueline);
```

**Edit**

```
.line {fill:none; stroke:red;}
```

Comment: thank you, this is helpful, hoever I still have some troubles. https://jsfiddle.net/o1up890k/1/

Comment: set the fill style for the line to `none`